# CSS varibale in own style

Tags: javascript, css

I'am not profficient in html and css, so i dont even know how to search for a post here in StackOverflow I excuse my selfe beforehand if this is an duplicate.

i want to do something like this:

```
margin-horizontal
{
   margin-left: var;
   margin-right: var;
}

<div style="margin-horizontal: 50px">
```

Is there a way to accomplish this behavior?

Comment: so you want to apply horizontal margin of 50px to your div.

Comment: You can implement same functionality like mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Chris05's answer: you can also programmatically set the CSS variables from JavaScript.

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--space', '150px');
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--space2', '20px');
```

```css
:root {
  --space: 50px;
  --space2: 50px;
}

div {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #454545;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.margin-horizontal {
  margin-left: var(--space);
  margin-right: var(--space);
}

.margin-horizontal2 {
  margin-left: var(--space2);
  margin-right: var(--space2);
}
```

```html
<div class="margin-horizontal">150px margins</div>
<div class="margin-horizontal2">20px margins</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

[CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) are possibly what you are looking for. Your example would look as follows.

CSS:

```
:root {
 --space: 50px;
}

.margin-horizontal
{
   margin-left: var(--space);
   margin-right: var(--space);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="margin-horizontal">...</div>
```

Comment: although I was hoping for a more elegant answer this is propably the closest we will get to the functionality I had in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer by @chris05, if you want to have *different* values of margins for different divs, you can add a class that sets the CSS variable to a different value, for instance:

```
  .m-25 {
    --space: 25px;
  }

  .m-75 {
    --space: 75px;
  }
```

Then your default will be 50px, and if you want a different one you just add a modifier class:

```
<div class="margin-horizontal">Foo</div>
<div class="m-25 margin-horizontal">Bar</div>
```

and you'll see:

[image: HTML rendering]

Answer (score -1):

What exactly are you hoping to get?

If you want to use your css class in your html you want to give the div a class with the name 'margin-horizontal'. like this: div class="margin-horizontal"